# In some zoom levels there's a horizontal line above the top buttons

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

Using Chrome 17.0.963.56 on Windows 7 with 120 DPI.

Appearance at 100% zoom:

[image: button bar at 100% zoom]

Appearance at 110% zoom:

[image: button bar at 110% zoom]

Going over all possible zoom levels, it looks okay on
25%, 50%, 100%, 150%, 200%, 250%, 300%, 400% and 500%
and appears broken (horizontal bar on top) on
33%, 67%, 75%, 90%, 110%, 125% and 175%.

Now I do not expect perfect layouts on different zoom levels, but I don't expect extra lines to appear from nowhere, either. (well, not necessarily nowhere - it looks as if it came from the button line)

Comment: Desktop browser zoom is FUBAR so I'm not sure if we support it on any cosmetic level.

Comment: Is it just how you snapped the screenies or is that really the bottom line of the buttons seems to not be part of the buttons and so scale out differently (ie, its a background image and they dont scale at all)?

Comment: This is (I think) because the buttons/tabs themselves are actually a single image, overlaid on a green background.  When you scale it, and it doesn't exactly fill the green rectangle, bits of the green leak through.  You can see the entire PNG [here](http://cdn.sstatic.net/gaming/img/sprites-extra.png?v=4).  Potentially, making the black tabs a few pixels higher would mask this issue.